# Equal sign in enumerate label

Tags: enumerate

Is it possible to use `=` in an enumerate label?

Like so:

```
k=1: item1
k=2: item2
```

The following example doesn't seem to work.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=k=\arabic*:]
    \item item1
    \item item2
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `label={k=\arabic*:}`.

Comment: Quite likely, `label={$k=\arabic*$}` is better.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please be sure to include a minimum working example with your question.  Also, "doesn't seem to work" is much too vague; what exactly happens?